# Throwing Exception when sum up the response array values

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, nsarray

Hi I'm getting following exception when I try to sum up the values of a response array from both the method mentioned below.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c463ade0'
```

### Tried code below

```
-(void)getSelectedServiceTypeArray:(NSArray *)selectedServicesTypeArray
{
    NSInteger sum = 0;
    selectedMultiServiceType = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:selectedServicesTypeArray, nil];
    NSArray *priceArray = [selectedMultiServiceType valueForKey:@"price_per_unit"];
    NSLog (@"PriceArray%@",priceArray);
  //  sum = [priceArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"];
    for (NSNumber *num in priceArray)
    {
        sum += [num intValue];
        NSLog(@"SUMR1%ld",(long)sum);
    }

    NSLog(@"SSTAA%@",selectedMultiServiceType);


}
```

Mean while I tried both the method for an array contains manually entered values. Anyway Both methods works for this..

```
NSArray *testArray = @[@"24",@"75",@"80",@"44"];

    NSNumber *sum = [testArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"];
    NSLog(@"SUM SUM1%@",sum);


     double sum2 = 0;
     for (NSNumber *serviceFeeTotal in testArray)
     {
     sum2  += [serviceFeeTotal doubleValue];
     }
     NSLog(@"SUM SUM2%f",sum2);
```

I don't why this not working and app is crashing on either of both methods when I using an array that retrieved from a previous ViewController by delegate method.

Response of the array I tried to sum up

```
PriceArray(
        (
        30,
        45
    )
)
```

Please explain me with a proper code...

Thanks for the All the support I solved the issue by replacing following code

```
selectedMultiServiceType = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:selectedServicesTypeArray, nil];
    **NSArray *priceArray = [selectedMultiServiceType[0] valueForKey:@"price_per_unit"];**
    NSLog (@"PriceArray%@",priceArray);
```

Comment: If you'd define `PriceArray` the same way you did with `testArray` it should be `PriceArray = @[@[@"30", @"45"]]` (array inside array of string numbers, and not array of string numbers). That's why it fails. You don't have the same structure on your "working solution" and the "real one". The crash loggued error is saying so. You are using `valueForKey:`, but I'm not sure you are ready for that, you may be unprepare to the result it gives.

Comment: SELECTEDIDS(
        {
        "price_per_unit" = 30;
        "sub_cat_id" = 591d666f2279517a0c004ad8;
        "sub_cat_name" = "Water Leak";
        unit = 1;
    },
        {
        "price_per_unit" = 60;
        "sub_cat_id" = 591d6680227951690c004ad7;
        "sub_cat_name" = "Drainage Clogging ";
        unit = 1;
    }
)

Comment: @Larme Above was the response of the array that I used valueForKey: to get the priceArray.. Any idea to properly filter / access ?

Comment: In `for (NSNumber *num in priceArray)`, `num` is in fact a `NSArray`, not a `NSNumber`, print it you'll see. So `sum += [num intValue];` will crash, because since `num` is a `NSArray` it doesn't know `intValue` method.

Comment: @Larme Any Solution for this ?

Comment: Change `NSNumber *num` to `NSArray *numArray` and then fix the content of the loop to do what you want with potentially multiple arrays.

Comment: Ok. I got your issue. `[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:selectedServicesTypeArray, nil]` => `[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:selectedServicesTypeArray]` That's the one adding a extra level of array (embedding in a array). The print you gave: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668424/throwing-exception-when-sum-up-the-response-array-values#comment84335262_48668424 is `selectedServicesTypeArray`, but you apply your calculation on `priceArray`.

Comment: Please Check the Edited Section to know, how I managed to solve this issue.